# TimeZone in Strongloop API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I am trying to defined timezone for specific region(India) in Strong loopback but I am unable to find a solution.

I am using this code to defined the timezone in strong loopback.

```
 var moment = require('moment-timezone');    
 var time_moment= moment().tz("Asia/Kolkata").format();
```

I am also use another code to defined the timezone,
I defined the timezone in datasource.json but asusual is not working.

```
"host": "localhost",
"port": "3306",
"database": "test_check",
"username": "root",
"password": "",
"name": "new_file",
"connector": "mysql",
"timezone": "UTC+05:30"
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? How are you trying to use the timezone? How is your code failing?

Comment: Basically, I use loopback API and through this I save the time in database, but when I save the time they save according to US time means If I save 12:30 they save 7:00( 5:30 before). Please give me a solution to defined the Indian timezone in strongloop.

Comment: Have your resolved this? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new time-zone as follows:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var unpackedTimezone = {
    name    : 'Asia/Kolkata',
    abbrs   : ['IST'],
    untils  : [null],
    offsets : [-330]
};
var packedTimezone = moment.tz.pack(unpacked);
var timezone = moment.tz.add(packedTimezone);
```

Here **while IST (Indian standard time) is UTC+530, the UTC offset in the array has to be the additive inverse (negative) of (5*60) + 30 = 330 for some reason. Therefore, the offset is [-330]**.

This was just to show how to create the timezone. You can also use the one provided by the developers at their [github](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json#L178) page.

Comment: No, its not working,When we use these code console time is ok but when this was save in database they save 5 hours 30 min behinds.Please give me any solution to save default indian standard time in strongloop API.

Answer (score 0):

since Loopback use mysql.js; you can set timezone based on the @@global.time_zone value.

you can add the timezone as follows:

```
"host": "localhost",
"port": "3306",
"database": "test_check",
"username": "root",
"password": "",
"name": "new_file",
"connector": "mysql",
"timezone": "Asia/Kolkata"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
let d = moment("2018-07-16T02:40:20.000Z", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").add(moment().utcOffset()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```